# how to .animate div in jQuery, but it contains divs in that div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, jquery-animate

My English is bad, but I'll try to explain.
I really need, help.
I want to make animation with div, so div height change from 0px to height 500px:

```
$(".link").click(function(){
   $("#container").animate({height: '500'}, 1000);
});
```

but my problem is that div #container contains 5 more divs, and when i make this code, it doesnt work because of those 5 divs. When I delete those 5 divs it works.
How to make it to work with those 5 div in that div #container.

Plese, help. Thanks.

Comment: please share the relevant html

Comment: does not work like? does height? down the other div's?

Comment: Does the div initially have a height of 0? or is it auto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/ppollono/EhaV7/)

HTML

```
<a class="link">button</a>

<div id="container">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(".link").click(function () {
    $("#container").animate({
        height: '200'
    }, 1000);
});
```

CSS

```
#container {
    height:0;
    background: red;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#container div {

}
```